# symfony 4 Form unit test not working

Tags: phpunit, symfony4

Hi I'm trying to test form in symfony 4. This ismy code,

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/user/new');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form(array(
            'user[displayName]' => 'user',
            'user[username]' => 'user@yahoo.com',
            'user[password]' => 'user123',
            'user[phoneNumber]' => '1234789',
            'user[roles]' => 'ROLE_USER',
        ));
        $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
        $this->assertGreaterThan(
                0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Your changes were saved!")')->count()
        );
```

Form has the values but all I get is,

> Failed asserting that 0 is greater than 0.

when actual submit I get this alert.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    Your changes were saved!
</div>
```

It would be if someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears to be needed to follow the redirect since form submission is always redirected.

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/user/new');

        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form(array(
            'user[displayName]' => 'user',
            'user[username]' => 'user@yahoo.com',
            'user[password]' => 'user123',
            'user[phoneNumber]' => '1234789',
            'user[roles]' => 'ROLE_USER',
        ));
        $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();

        $this->assertGreaterThan(
                0, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Your changes were saved!")')->count()
        );
```